# try to use the mongoosedb in nextjs app and getting errors

Tags: typescript, mongoose, next.js, next-auth

**1. TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.connect is not a function**

```js
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
let alreadyDone = false;

export async function connectToDatabase():Promise<void> {
    if (alreadyDone) {
        return;
    }

    alreadyDone = true;
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, dbName: "User" });
}
```

This is the code to connect to the db;

**2. TypeError: *lib_db__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2*_.User.findOne is not a function**

```js
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"
import { User } from "@/lib/db";
import { connectToDatabase } from "@/lib/dbConnect";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function balance() {
    const session = useSession();
    const [money, setBalance] = useState(0);
    console.log(session);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            let balanceValue = 0;
            console.log('Connecting to database...');
            await connectToDatabase();your text
            console.log('Connected!');
            if (session.data) {
                const you = session.data?.user?.email;
                console.log('Searching for user:', you);
                const admin = await User.findOne({username:you});
                console.log('Found user:', admin);
                balanceValue = admin ? admin.balance : 0;
            }
            setBalance(balanceValue);
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [session]);

    return ( <div>{money} <div> )
}
```